# Fiil a data on a certain field of record from another form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have to fill text data "OK" on 'txtProcessed' (a texbox) of 'AccDocOrder" form where 'txtDocOrderID' (also a text box, and it contains the Primary Key ) has a value = 3 from another form named 'DocStock' form. 
Other words;
I have to fill text data "OK" on 'Processed' column of 'AccDocOrder' table where 'DocOrderID' = 3 ('DocOrderID' is Primary Key of 'AccDocOrder' table)from another form named 'DocStock'form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want, but if you simply want to populate a text box in another form then you could try this. Note: You need the following code in "DocSTock" form

```
if DocOrderID.value = "3"
   AccDocOrder.txtProcessed.value = "OK"
   Frm_PivotDetail.Show
end if
```

Comment: I am a newbie, please inform me if I have to make new form name Frm_PivotDetail.show.

Comment: I have run the program but 'OK' sign alway appear on the most top record, it is not enter itu a record which DocOrderID is 3.

Comment: I have run the program but 'OK' sign always appear on the most top record, it is not enter into a record which DocOrderID is 3.

Comment: Can you post some more of the code you have developed and provide some more detail regarding what you want to achieve?